# Phase portrait of ODE in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, stability-in-odes

Given the system of ODEs in polar coordinates, $$r' = r(1-r^2)(4-r^2)$$ $$\theta'=2-r^2,$$

one can determine its equilibrium points and limit cycles as follows:

$\gamma_1:= \begin{cases} r = 0,\\ \theta = 2t\end{cases}$, $\gamma_2:= \begin{cases} r = 1,\\ \theta = t\end{cases}$, $\gamma_3:= \begin{cases} r = 2,\\ \theta = -2t\end{cases}$.

$\gamma_1$ corresponds to $(0,0)$ in the $xy$-plane, and $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ correspond to circles.

Now I need to sketch the phase portrait of this system and, based on this sketch, determine the stability of the equilibrium points and limit cycles.

Does one need to solve this system explicitly in order to sketch the phase portrait, or is there a neater way to do it, without solving the system?

I've also tried with solving for the ODE in terms of $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, but it doesn't appear to be an equation which is easy to plot either.

Also, do you think that I've found all the possible limit cycles, or maybe missed something? I'm new to this kind of analysis.

Comment: You also know that at $r=\sqrt2$ the paths reverse orientation. Determine the signs of $\dot r$ between the stationary points.

Comment: @LutzL: by a stationary point, do you mean the points where the paths reverse orientation?

Comment: I mean the points where $\dot r=0$, as they separate regions where $\dot r$ has a constant sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:** I would have made this a comment if I could.

Here is the polar plot.

[image]

Here is the transformed system, if you want to validate the rest of your analysis using other approaches.

$$x' = x \left(-x^2-y^2+1\right) \left(-x^2-y^2+4\right)-\frac{y \left(-x^2-y^2+2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\ y' = y \left(-x^2-y^2+1\right) \left(-x^2-y^2+4\right) + \frac{x \left(-x^2-y^2+2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

**Update** Reduced the plot area to see further detail in the areas of interest.

[image]

Comment: I'll hand-sketch it by analyzing the polar coordinates equations and then will compare it to your sketch. BTW, which application did you use to generate this sketch?

Comment: Mathematica, but you can use Maxima, Matlab, Maple or some other [*CAS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). Also, notice the critical points of your equations at $0, \pm 1, \pm 2$ and the direction change mentioned by @LutzL at $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The arrows don't change direction on your phase portrait above, but maybe their bending indicates that?  @Moo

Comment: @Moo please retain it for reference. The vector field directions should be understood esp. with my one LC sketch.

Comment: @sequence: See updated diagram for more detail.

Comment: @Moo: thanks much. How exactly does the change of direction happen in terms of the arrows at $r=\sqrt{2}$? I'm trying to spot how the reversal of direction happens exactly.

Comment: I think it may be hard to spot in these diagrams. If you look at numerical data for $r'$ and $\theta'$, you can see the directions, but that might not be as simple for the angle change given we are working in polar. To be honest, I haven't thought about it much. Hopefully, there was enough here for you to make progress in drawing the phase portrait.

Comment: +1 (if only for the second picture). // Did you enter the equivalent $(x,y)$-differential system in the program to get the picture or is there a way to enter only the $(r,\theta)$-differential system?

Comment: @Did - thanks: For the polar plot, here are steps: field = {r (1 - r^2) (4 - r^2), 2 - r^2};, StreamPlot[
 Evaluate@TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   field, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]. You can also do TransformedField[
 "Polar" -> "Cartesian", field, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}], and then use StremPlot as you normally do. Note, there are slashes in front of the Theta terms, but they don't show up for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 1&2

[image: 3 Regions]

Before coming to phase portrait, I thought of gaining understanding of LC loci numerically.

The limit cycle LC (above) are running  in $ r<1, r=1 - 2, r >2 $ three regions. In the central region there is a a turnaround at radial direction of velocity at $r= \sqrt 2 $. When started inside $r<1$ it cannot cross $r =1$. Starting inside the annulus must remain there between the two circular asymptotes . Motion $r>2 cannot enter the annulus at all.

Without solving you can plot  first PP $ (r, r^{'} ) $ but one cannot plot second PP $ (\theta, \theta ^{'}) $ without solving the full system either analytically or numerically. There are two circle boundaries at $ r= (1,2)$ and a radial tangent at $ \theta^{'} =0, r = \sqrt 2.$

Where exactly the outer radial asymptotic comes about $ $ r>r2$  ... is yet to be understood (by me).

Comment: The system being invariant by rotation centered at $r=0$, every value of $\theta$ is equivalent and I fail to understand the mention of "a radial tangent at $\theta=\sqrt2$".

Comment: Very sorry, typo corrected.

Comment: Is this supposed to describe a solution? Note that no solution starting from some point with $r<1$ escapes the region $r<1$. Likewise for the regions $1<r<2$ and $r>2$.

Comment: Updated inside circle motion, I got motion in three zones as you indicated. Green/magenta lines stopping at a definite outermost edge .. this boundary I am unable to grasp.

Comment: Once again, no solution with at least one point in $r>2$ ever meets the region $r\leqslant2$. No idea what the four colored curves in your diagram are supposed to be (the green one is not a solution, anyway, even approximately).

Comment: Yes, $r> \sqrt 2 $ to $ r < \sqrt 2 $ continuity cannot be there, agree with you there.(The green line can be ignored, reg direction in previous discussion graph). My only question is what marks max radius of magenta.